# Same query uses 2 different plans in 2 sessions

Tags: oracle

I am running same query in 2 different DB sessions but it is ending up picking 2 different plans. One is faster and other takes hours.
Any ideas on how to make them use same plan:

This is Plan for faster query
[image: Faster Query Plan]

This is plan for slower query
[image: Poor query plan]

Only difference between 2 plans is order of collection iterator pickler fetch

EDIT:

Just to add more details, above query is not really a standard query as it uses `Table` function which accepts a dynamic array list.

Comment: Everything is same for 2 sessions. Just to add number of elements in array passed might be a slightly different

Comment: I'm taking a guess here.
Please try to add **FIRST_ROWS** hint. --- P.s. Different parameters may lead to different execution plans.
look for **bind peeking**

Comment: Lokesh, the execution plans are totally different.For start, the first one uses **INDEX RANGE SCAN** and **INDEX FAST FULL SCAN** while the second uses **INDEX SKIP SCAN**, **INDEX UNIQUE SCAN** and **HASH JOIN**.

Comment: In the second query, the cardinality of pickler fetch is 8168, which seems a default cardinality for 8k block (for table functions). You might want to estimate and provide cardinality your table function (don't think it is 8168) which will help. Also looking at query, it might make sense to rewrite the query, so that you first join instrument and table function in pky). Join the output with quotes, I am also guessing the quotes table will probably have a FK to instrument. So, that will help too. Good luck.

Comment: your code should look like (apologies, i haven't figured out formatting in comments yet)   `with x as (select i.pkey as instrument_pkey, i.type as instrument_type, lbd.maxbackdays from instruments i, table(cast(:historic_array as reporting_historic_tab)) lbd where lbd.instrument = i.pkey ) select x.pkey as instrument_pkey, p.asof ...      from x join quotes_maxequities p on (x.pkey = p.instrument) where pkasof between :ASOF - x.maxbackdays and :ASOF and p.owner = SOURCE_ID;`

Answer (score 3):

You could create an optimizer extension to handle statistics for your collection, so the optimizer doesn't have to guess the value of its cardinality, selectivity and cost.

This can be done with the SQL statement ASSOCIATE STATISTICS:
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_statscon.htm#TGSQL339

In order to implement the statistics collection interface, please have a look at:
http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADDCI/ext_optimizer.htm#ADDCI2110

Another option is to use the undocumented CARDINALITY hint, which I would personally not recommend.

For an example of statistics association, please check the code below:

```
-- Creates a collection type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varchar2_ntt AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

-- Creates a function wrapper to the collection
CREATE FUNCTION collection_wrapper(
                p_collection IN varchar2_ntt
                ) RETURN varchar2_ntt IS
BEGIN
  RETURN p_collection;
END collection_wrapper;
/

-- Create an object type specification to handle statistics collection
-- on the function wrapper
CREATE TYPE collection_wrapper_ot AS OBJECT (
  dummy_attribute NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIGetInterfaces (
                  p_interfaces OUT SYS.ODCIObjectList
                  ) RETURN NUMBER,

  STATIC FUNCTION ODCIStatsTableFunction (
                  p_function   IN  SYS.ODCIFuncInfo,
                  p_stats      OUT SYS.ODCITabFuncStats,
                  p_args       IN  SYS.ODCIArgDescList,
                  p_collection IN varchar2_ntt
                  ) RETURN NUMBER

);
/

-- Statistics interface implementation
-- Basically returns the count on the collection as its cardinality
CREATE TYPE BODY collection_wrapper_ot AS

   STATIC FUNCTION ODCIGetInterfaces (
                   p_interfaces OUT SYS.ODCIObjectList
                   ) RETURN NUMBER IS
   BEGIN
       p_interfaces := SYS.ODCIObjectList(
                           SYS.ODCIObject ('SYS', 'ODCISTATS2')
                           );
       RETURN ODCIConst.success;
   END ODCIGetInterfaces;

   STATIC FUNCTION ODCIStatsTableFunction (
                   p_function   IN  SYS.ODCIFuncInfo,
                   p_stats      OUT SYS.ODCITabFuncStats,
                   p_args       IN  SYS.ODCIArgDescList,
                   p_collection IN  varchar2_ntt
                   ) RETURN NUMBER IS
   BEGIN
      p_stats := SYS.ODCITabFuncStats(p_collection.COUNT);
      RETURN ODCIConst.success;
   END ODCIStatsTableFunction;

END;
/

-- Associate the statistics type with the function wrapper
ASSOCIATE STATISTICS WITH FUNCTIONS collection_wrapper USING collection_wrapper_ot;
```

Now you can check the effects on the execution plan:

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain

SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   TABLE(varchar2_ntt('A','B','C'));

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1748000095

--------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Rows  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |  8168 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------

SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   TABLE(
  3            collection_wrapper(
  4               varchar2_ntt('A','B','C')));

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4261576954

------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name               | Rows  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                    |     3 |
|   1 |  COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| COLLECTION_WRAPPER |       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

PS.: The code above was adapted from http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=427.